# BingAPIv7 paging mechanism not working for both Web and News search

Tags: api, bing

We have tried the Bing V7 paging mechanism for both Web and News.
count=100 for news, count=50 for web, as per the documentation.

However, very quickly (around offset=200) the number of returned results is less than 5, and in any case the results are duplicates of already returned pages. The ApproxCount also indicates a problem: starts out as millions and when the offset is increased it quickly becomes 400 or less.

News query example [Here](https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news/search?q=%27soccer%27&offset=0&count=100)

Thanks in advance,

Ofer

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be similar for all search APIs across different offerings. This has to do with 1) Cost of indexing huge number of webpages, and 2) Utility of those. Most users finish their search within first 2 pages or search with a new string again. So, even if you have millions of matched pages, they are potentially useless. Search engines do this to optimize their indexing and reduce serving redundant pages - you already see some with higher offset values.

You can restrict users to go to very high offset pages by 1) Having related searches, and 2) Taking care from UX side.